# Find remarkable elements in house using opencv Python

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I have very few images on houses such as this one.
I am looking at detecting door, windows, roof (whenever possible) and extracting some key measures. I have been playing :-) / testing with:

1. Sharpening, blurring & thresholding
2. Detecting special materials in HSV range (including reflection on glazing)
3. Extracting and post-processing contours that are aligned with Y

This work to a certain extent but not generalize very well depending on the type of roof and/or color of the walls - and it is quite frequent to miss one openening ;-)

When it comes to measures my plan is to take into account the fact that most windows / doors have standard know sizes.

Do you have different approaches that I might not have tried so far - I tried to look at datasets or pre-trained NN like (cityscape) but my own dataset is way too small.

Do you also have some idea how to retrieve basic 3d information from a single picture ?

I can share colab if useful

Thanks
Guillaume

[image: one]]